# Почему не возвращается значение из JsonObjectRequest?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть функция запроса `JsonObjectRequest`, где мне нужно получить `String`. Это моя функция:

```
fun getName(
       id: String,
        requestResult: (res: JSONObject) -> Unit,
        requestError: ((err: String) -> Unit)? = null
    ) {

val requestUrl = "https://api/app/getherp/get?$id"

        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, null,
            { response ->
               requestResult(response)

            },
            { error ->
              
                requestError?.invoke(error.toString());
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                return getAuthHeaders()
            }
        }
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
```

значение, которое возвращается в результате этого запроса, мне нужно передать в качестве параметра в  функцию `addInList` во фрагменте. Вот функция `addInList`:

```
 private fun addInList(name:String) {
  
       list.add(0, UserInfo(name))
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

и затем я вызываю эту функцию. так же во фрагменте:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
......
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
.....
uploadPer()
.....
}

private fun uploadPer(){
 id = user.id
                    val mId = id
                    if (mId != null) {
                        val name= MyClass.getName(mId,
                            { res->
    
                            },
                            { err ->
    
                            }).toString()
    
                        addInList(name)
                    }
}
    private fun addInList(name:String) {

       list.add(0, UserInfo(name))
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Приложение отрабатывает, эксепшенов нет. Но в качестве имени в список возвращается всегда одно значение: "kotlin.unit" . Не могу понять, как это исправить. Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: что такое requestResult?

Comment: это результат запроса

Comment: а где происходит вызов addItem, добавьте полный код в вопрос

Comment: во фрагменте в другом методе, который вызывается в методе `onCreateView`

Comment: я не вижу этого в вопросе, я не понимаю куда и что у вас передаётся

Comment: я отредактировала вопрос

Comment: окей, всё ещё не вижу вызова метода addItem + заметил getName возвращает Unit, а вы думаете что там имя. Вы по какому туториалу это делаете?

Comment: ни по какому туториалу не делаю, посмотрела примеры просто. внесла исправления , перепутала названия методов. и да, думаю Вы правы, что проблема в том, что функция `getName` возвращает  `Unit` , а мне нужен тип `String`. Но не могу сообразить. как исправить код,что бы  `getName`  возвращал во фрагменте тип `String`

Comment: Дело в том, что запрос на сервер отправляется асинхронно, наверное вам нужно почитать что это такое. Само имя придёт только внутрь вашего тела переданной функции { res-> }, но когда именно это произойдёт неизвестно, попробуйте конечно заменить этот код на {res-> addInList(res) }, но не уверен, что это именно, то что вы ожидаете

Comment: спасибо за совет. я попробую.